# Uploading a single image to Facebook wall

Tags: upload, facebook

I'm looking to see if anyone knows of something (or similar) that could upload a single image to a user's Facebook wall? It should prompt or store a log in somewhere and let a user choose the image somehow.

The second part of the question is, if not, then is there anything in the Facebook URL that I could pass as an argument or something like `facebook.com/myUserName/uploadPath:C:\Users\Documents\img0001.jpg`. I know that this example is not even close, but I've been searching for a while and can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole/) module for python.

To upload a photo you would use

```
fbconsole.post('/me/photos', {'source':open('my-photo.jpg')})
```